# How to block IP Address in ASA5505 firewall via ASDM?

Tags: access-control-list, cisco

I have an ASA5505 firewall and I need to block an external IP address which is talking to my server.

Basically, the ASA firewall shows that my server is "attacking" this Destination Address. So the Source IP is i.e. 192.168.100.100 which is internal, attacking 188.247.70.93 on port 80 thru the inside interface. which is outside.

I have blocked the IP from my server firewall but I need to know how to block it from the ASA Firewall via asdm as I am not too familiar with CLI

I mean, I did create an ACL with all the entries and applied it to the Inside interface, but then I have to create another rule to allow any to any for outgoing otherwise the firewall blocks all outgoing.

The problem with creating any to any is that as soon as I create that I saw 350+ hits on that rule. So how do I go about doing this block without compromising my system?

Thank you

Comment: Please show us your configuration, including which commands you've tried.